# define a link (GET) on trigger

Tags: mysql, t-sql

How can I send my mysql table parameters to a link through GET?

e.x. : `http:/example.com/Send.ashx?id=[member.id]&name=[class.name]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access MySQL via http directly. You will need to set up a rest API server that handles http requests, makes the corresponding SQL queries, formats the result (typically as json or XML) and sends it back to the client.

In case you already have an API / web server, we need more detailed information on your setup